# Eclipse 4.23.0 Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, rmi

I'm working through the proxy pattern section in Head First Design Patterns 2nd edition, by Freeman and Robson. I'm running Windows 10 and I've determined that localhost is functioning properly as the Windows IIS screen comes up when i navigate to localhost or http://127.0.0.1/. rmiregistry is started beforehand from the cmd line with no issue. I'm running the test with the firewall turned off and I'm still getting the error stack trace listed below. I'm executing the GumballMachineTestDrive class directly in Eclipse by right clicking on the .java file and selecting "Run As" "Java Application". The screenshot below shows the run configurations for GumballMachineTestDrive, where args[0] == "localhost" and args [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWTbO.png) == 112. I've pinged localhost and 127.0.0.1, both of which show no issues. I previously tried to set the rmi server hostname as can be seen in the line "System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "127.0.0.1");", however this did not make a difference. Any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

[image: GumballMachineTestDrive-Run Configurations]

**Service code:**

```
package GumballMachineStatePattern;

import java.rmi.Naming;

public class GumballMachineTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GumballMachineRemote gumballMachine = null;
        
    //  System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "127.0.0.1");
        
        int count;
        
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("GumballMachine <name> <inventory>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        try {
        
        count = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        
        gumballMachine = new GumballMachine(args[0], count);
        Naming.rebind("//" + args[0] + "/gumballmachine", gumballMachine);
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

**Code for GumballMachine class:**

```
package GumballMachineStatePattern;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class GumballMachine extends UnicastRemoteObject implements GumballMachineRemote {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

State soldOutState;
State noQuarterState;
State hasQuarterState;
State soldState;
State winnerState;

State state = soldOutState;
int count = 0;

String location;
    
    public GumballMachine(String location, int count) throws RemoteException {
        soldOutState = new SoldOutState(this);
        noQuarterState = new NoQuarterState(this);
        hasQuarterState = new HasQuarterState(this);
        soldState = new SoldState(this);
        winnerState = new WinnerState(this);
        
        this.location = location;
        
        this.count = count;
        if (count > 0) {
            state = noQuarterState;
        } else {
            state = soldOutState;
        }
    }
    
    public void insertQuarter() {
        state.insertQuarter();
    }
    
    public void ejectQuarter() {
        state.ejectQuarter();
    }
    
    public void turnCrank() {
        state.turnCrank();
        state.dispense();
    }
    
    void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    
    void releaseBall() {
        System.out.println("A gumball comes rolling out of the slot...");
        if (count > 0) {
            count = count - 1;
        }
    }
    
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    
    void refill(int count) {
        this.count += count;
        System.out.println("The gumball machine was just refilled; its new count is: " + this.count);
        state.refill();
    }
    
    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }
    
    public State getSoldOutState() {
        return soldOutState;
    }
    
    public State getNoQuarterState() {
        return noQuarterState;
    }
    
    public State getHasQuarterState() {
        return hasQuarterState;
    }
    
    public State getSoldState() {
        return soldState;
    }
    
    public State getWinnerState() {
        return winnerState;
    }
    
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
        
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        result.append("\nMighty Gumball, Inc.");
        result.append("\nJave-enabled Standing Gumball Model #2004\n");
        result.append("Inventory: " + count + " gumball");
        
        if (count != 1) {
            result.append("s");
        }
        result.append("\n");
        result.append("Machine is " + state + "\n");
        
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

**GumballMachineTestDrive stack trace where args[0] == "localhost" and args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWTbO.png) = 112**

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:626)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:217)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:204)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:344)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:150)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at GumballMachineStatePattern.GumballMachineTestDrive.main(GumballMachineTestDrive.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:507)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:287)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:620)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: You're trying to access localhost at port 112.   Is your IIS running on port 112?

Comment: Java and RMI are unrelated to IIS. You should read [Getting Started Using Java™ RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html). **Especially** [Start the Java RMI registry, server, and client](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#start).

Comment: ewong, the integer 112 is passed to args[1], which is passed as the second argument in the "GumballMachine" constructor. It represents the initial count of gumballs in the GumballMachine. Elliot, my thinking was that with IIS enabled and showing at "localhost", I would be able to rule out firewall issues. I will review the recommended documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I needed to re-do the project as a fresh java project to clear up what were probably some dependency conflicts. It also served as a good learning lesson rmi and xampp local server configuration as well.